# Increasing and decreasing piecewise function on an interval

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, continuity

I'm working on a problem that involves finding the intervals where a function $f$ is increasing and decreasing. Given the function$$ f(x) = 
\cases{
x+7  & \text{if } x\lt -3\cr
|x+1| & \text{if } -3\le x <1\cr 
5-2x  & \text{if } x\ge 1\cr
}$$
I worked out that $f$ is increasing on $(-\infty,-3)$ and $[-1,1)$ , and $f$ is decreasing on $[-3,-1], [1,\infty)$.

However, the solution in the book claims that $f$ is increasing on $[-1,1]$, rather than $[-1,1)$ like I worked out. I am having trouble understanding why the book claims that this is the case.

I was under the impression that $f$ must be differentiable on the interior of an interval $I$ and continuous on all of $I$ in order to make any statements about increasing/decreasing behavior on the closed interval $I$. I'm not sure if I am overlooking something, but it seems that $f$ is not continuous on $[-1,1]$. I would appreciate any clarification.

Comment: I would say that a function is increasing in an open interval if, given $x$ and $y$ in the interval, we have $x<y \Rightarrow f(x)<f(y)$.  No need for continuity.  I'd say the function was increasing at a point if it is increasing in some open interval containing that point.  Your function fails that at $x=1$.  It is increasing to the left of $1$ but to the right it is clearly decreasing.

Comment: I am having trouble reconciling the requirement that $f$ be continuous on $[-1,1]$ in order to claim that $f$ is increasing on $[-1,1]$. It seems clear that $f$ is not continuous on $[-1,1]$, so according to the theorem stated in my book, I shouldn't be able to state that $f$ is increasing on $[-1,1]$.

Comment: Interesting...it seems that everyone (but me) is correct that the usual definition would allow you to say that your function is increasing on [-1,1]  because that question only has meaning within that interval.  I yield to the majority.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is true that if you have a differentiable function on an interval, then it is increasing if and only if its derivative is non-negative. However, increasing functions need not be differentiable according to their definition:
$\def\rr{\mathbb{R}}$

A function $f : \rr \to \rr$ is increasing on a collection $S$ if and only if:

For any $x,y \in S$ such that $x \le y$:

$f(x) \le f(y)$.

Note that this definition is incompatible with the one that lulu proposed in a comment, but I believe this is the typical definition.

Comment: For what it's worth, I'd call your function "non-decreasing".  I actually don't know what the standard is...it could well be as you say.

Comment: @lulu: I too would call it "non-decreasing", but apparently people just call it "increasing" and use "strictly increasing" for the one where the inequality signs are all strict.

Comment: You are exactly correct.  I've looked in several references and everybody defines it just as you have.  Seems off to me, but there is no point in arguing with standard usage.  Thanks for updating me!

Comment: @lulu: I suppose one factor is that "non-decreasing" is four extra characters.

Answer (score 0):

You have found that $f$ is increasing on $[-1,1)$.

Now
$$
\lim_{x \to 1^-}f(x)=|1+1|=2<3=f(1)
$$
Thus $f$ is increasing on $[-1,1]$.